# MongoDB query and projection on subdocument array returns also array of another document

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I am trying to query an embedded subdocument and then only return an array in that subdocument via [projection](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/#projection-operators). After a query you can select fields that you want returned via projection. I want to use the native functionality because it is possible and the most clean way. The problem is it returns arrays in two documents.

I tried different query and projection options, but no result.

**User model**

```
             // Define station schema
             const stationSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
                mac: String,
                stationName: String,
                syncReadings: Boolean,
                temperature: Array,
                humidity: Array,
                measures: [{
                    date: Date,
                    temperature: Number,
                    humidity: Number
                }],
                lastUpdated: Date
            });

            // Define user schema
            var userSchema = mongoose.Schema({

                apiKey: String,
                stations : [stationSchema]

            },  {
                    usePushEach: true 
                }
            );
```

**api call**

```
       app.get('/api/stations/:stationName/measures',function(req, res, next) {

        var user = {
            apiKey: req.user.apiKey
        }

        const query = {
            apiKey: user.apiKey,
            'stations.stationName': req.params.stationName
        }

        const options = {
            'stations.$.measures': 1,
        }

        User.findOne(query, options)
        .exec()
        .then(stations => {     
            res.status(200).send(stations)
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
            res.status(400).send(err);
        })

    });
```

**Expected result**

```
   {
        "_id": "5c39c99356bbf002fb092ce9",
        "stations": [
            {
                "stationName": "livingroom",
                "measures": [
                    {
                        "humidity": 60,
                        "temperature": 20,
                        "date": "2019-01-12T22:49:45.468Z",
                        "_id": "5c3a6f09fd357611f8d078a0"
                    },
                    {
                        "humidity": 60,
                        "temperature": 20,
                        "date": "2019-01-12T22:49:46.500Z",
                        "_id": "5c3a6f0afd357611f8d078a1"
                    },
                    {
                        "humidity": 60,
                        "temperature": 20,
                        "date": "2019-01-12T22:49:47.041Z",
                        "_id": "5c3a6f0bfd357611f8d078a2"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
```

**Actual result**

```
   {
        "_id": "5c39c99356bbf002fb092ce9",
        "stations": [
            {
                "stationName": "livingroom",
                "measures": [
                    {
                        "humidity": 60,
                        "temperature": 20,
                        "date": "2019-01-12T22:49:45.468Z",
                        "_id": "5c3a6f09fd357611f8d078a0"
                    },
                    {
                        "humidity": 60,
                        "temperature": 20,
                        "date": "2019-01-12T22:49:46.500Z",
                        "_id": "5c3a6f0afd357611f8d078a1"
                    },
                    {
                        "humidity": 60,
                        "temperature": 20,
                        "date": "2019-01-12T22:49:47.041Z",
                        "_id": "5c3a6f0bfd357611f8d078a2"
                    }
                ]
            },
******************************************************
 // this whole object should not be returned
            {
              "stationName": "office",
                "measures": [] 
            }
******************************************************
        ]
    }
```

**edit**
The answer below with aggregation works, but I still find it odd that I would need so much code. If after my normal query I get the same result with ".stations[0].measures", instead of the whole aggregation pipeline:

```
.then(stations => {     
    res.status(200).send(stations.stations[0].measures)
})
```

The way I read the code, the above does exactly the same as:

```
const options = {'stations.$.measures': 1}
```

Where the dollar sign puts in the index 0 as that was the index of the station that matches the query part: stationName: "livingroom"

Can someone explain?

Comment: So you only want stations where at least one measure exists?

Comment: No, I only want the content of the measures array, from the station that I look for in my query: 

const query = {
            apiKey: user.apiKey,
            'stations.stationName': req.params.stationName
        }

It should only return the measures of "livingroom", but it also shows the station "office", as you can see in the results above. any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not described in terms of `mongoose` but this will find a particular station name in an array of stations in 1 or more docs and return only the `measures` array:

```
db.foo.aggregate([
// First, find the docs we are looking for:
{$match: {"stations.stationName": "livingroom"}}

// Got the doc; now need to fish out ONLY the desired station.  The filter will
// will return an array so use arrayElemAt 0 to extract the object at offset 0.
// Call this intermediate qqq:
,{$project: { qqq:
      {$arrayElemAt: [
          { $filter: {
            input: "$stations",
            as: "z",
            cond: { $eq: [ "$$z.stationName", "livingroom" ] }
      }}, 0]
      } 
}}

// Lastly, just project measures and not _id from this object:
,{$project: { _id:0, measures: "$qqq.measures" }}
                  ]);
```

Comment: This is the first answer that actually works with native mongoose functions. Could you tell me why projection doesn't work in the example I made? your's works better, as it ONLY returns the wanted data, but my problem above is that is also returns the measures array of a station dat is not matched by de station name in de query. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

[$elemMatch](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/elemMatch/)  operator limits the contents of an array field from the query results to contain only the first element matching the $elemMatch condition.

Try $elemMatch in Select Query as below :

```
const query = {
     apiKey: user.apiKey,
     'stations.stationName': req.params.stationName
}
const options = {
   'stations' : {$elemMatch: { 'stationName' : req.params.stationName }}
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I'll try this, but it still won't select and return only the measures array right?

Comment: yes, Give a try!as per your comment on the question, it will return measures of requested stationName(Expected Result)